# Getting the dictionary value greater than a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to get all the values in my dictionary list that have a value greater than 'string value'.  I've tried several of the iterations below plus several more.  What is the proper way to do this with a string value of a dictionary other than on the key?

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
lookupurl = "https://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/rxclass/allClasses.json?classTypes=ALL"  #REST API call for all class types
lookupdata = s.get(lookupurl).json()
lookup1 = lookupdata['rxclassMinConceptList']['rxclassMinConcept']


#lookup = [k for v,k in lookup1['classid'] if v >= 'D016849']  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
#lookup = [k for v,k in lookup1[0:]['classid'] if v >= 'D016849'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
#lookup = [k for v,k in lookup1[0]['classid'] if v >= 'D016849'] KeyError: 'classid'
#lookup = [v for k,v in lookup1['classid'] if k >= 'D016849']  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
#lookup = [v for k,v in lookup1[0:]['classid'] if k >= 'D016849'] KeyError: 'classid'
#lookup = [v for k,v in lookup1.classid() if k >= 'D016849']  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'classid'
#lookup = [v for k,v in lookup1.classid() if k >= 'D016849'] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
#lookup = dict(filter(lambda lookup1: lookup1['classid'] > 'D016849', lookup1['classid'])) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
#lookup = dict(filter(lambda lookup1: lookup1[0:]['classid'] > 'D016849', lookup1[0:]['classid'])) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
print(lookup)
```

My expected results would return only the classid's >= 'D016849'

Comment: You keep trying to access a key called "classid" but it doesn't exist. It won't appear by trying it more often.

Comment: `lookup1[0]['classid']` seems to be the correct form, assuming you were using a key that actually exists.

Comment: You should give an example `lookup1`. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, i thought having the code that pulls the dictionary would be sufficient.  It's over 100k lines.  You can vote to close this, i did as well.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. If you have a correct answer you want to share then please add it as a new answer in the answer space below. Don't edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lookup = [item for item in lookup1 if item['classId'] >= 'D016849']
```

I think the main problem is `classid` should be `classId`. Another issue is that you seem to be accessing `classId` on `lookup1` in many of your attempts. But actually, it's a property of *each element* in `lookup1`, not on `lookup1` itself.